# QT loading a webgl in a webengine using qt minimal example

Tags: qt, qml, unity-webgl, webengine

Good morning,
my goal is use WebEngine Qt Quick Minimal Example in order to visualize a WebGL in a qml window. From the original example I have just modified the url that is now pointing to my webGL file index.html.
When I run the application the unityWebGl page it opens and blocks here:

[image: Screenshot: loading is blocking here with some errors]

I have tried to run the same webgl file with the quicknanobrowser example and it can load and it works. Why with minimal example is not working?

This is the complete Application Output:

```
15:47:14: Starting C:\Users\diego\Desktop\QT\build-Elimina-Desktop_x86_windows_msvc2019_pe_32bit-Debug\debug\quicknanobrowser.exe ...
QML debugging is enabled. Only use this in a safe environment.
[3140:10684:1118/154718.047:INFO:CONSOLE(3)] "You can reduce your startup time if you configure your web server to host .unityweb files using brotli compression.", source: file:///C:/Users/diego/Desktop/WEBGL_BTC/WebGl/Build/UnityLoader.js (3)
[3140:10684:1118/154718.047:INFO:CONSOLE(3)] "You can reduce your startup time if you configure your web server to host .unityweb files using brotli compression.", source: file:///C:/Users/diego/Desktop/WEBGL_BTC/WebGl/Build/UnityLoader.js (3)
Received fatal exception EXCEPTION_BREAKPOINT
Received fatal exception EXCEPTION_BREAKPOINT
Received fatal exception EXCEPTION_BREAKPOINT
Backtrace:
Backtrace:
Backtrace:
    `anonymous namespace'::InvalidParameter [0x152CF3F3+3] (C:\Users\qt\work\qt\qtwebengine\src\3rdparty\chromium\base\win\process_startup_helper.cc:26)
    invalid_parameter [0x7AA6FBD7+151]
    std::_Vector_const_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<v8::internal::wasm::ValueBase> > >::operator* [0x11555382+194]
    std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<v8::internal::wasm::ValueBase> > >::operator* [0x115553CF+15]
    v8::internal::wasm::WasmFullDecoder<1,v8::internal::wasm::EmptyInterface>::TraceFailed [0x115737AB+1531]
    v8::internal::wasm::LiftoffAssembler::DeallocateStackSlot [0x1156470A+16570]
    v8::internal::wasm::LiftoffAssembler::DeallocateStackSlot [0x115607A8+344]
    v8::internal::wasm::ExecuteLiftoffCompilation [0x1156A65B+699]
    v8::internal::wasm::WasmCompilationUnit::ExecuteFunctionCompilation [0x11594F28+472]
    v8::internal::wasm::WasmCompilationUnit::ExecuteCompilation [0x11594CD3+115]
    v8::internal::wasm::AsyncStreamingProcessor::Deserialize [0x115B4168+1256]
    v8::internal::wasm::AsyncCompileJob::PrepareAndStartCompile::RunInForeground [0x115B89C8+488]
    v8::internal::CancelableTask::Run [0x10FE2CEC+44]
    base::internal::FunctorTraits<void (__thiscall printing::PrinterQuery::*)(void),void>::Invoke<void (__thiscall printing::PrinterQuery::*)(void),std::unique_ptr<printing::PrinterQuery,std::default_delete<printing::PrinterQuery> > > [0x0FBEA5F0+16] (C:\Users\qt\work\qt\qtwebengine\src\3rdparty\chromium\base\bind_internal.h:490)
    base::internal::InvokeHelper<0,void>::MakeItSo<void (__thiscall v8::Task::*)(void),std::unique_ptr<v8::Task,std::default_delete<v8::Task> > > [0x13D4C854+36] (C:\Users\qt\work\qt\qtwebengine\src\3rdparty\chromium\base\bind_internal.h:623)
    base::internal::Invoker<base::internal::BindState<void (__thiscall v8::Task::*)(void),std::unique_ptr<v8::Task,std::default_delete<v8::Task> > >,void __cdecl(void)>::RunImpl<void (__thiscall v8::Task::*)(void),std::tuple<std::unique_ptr<v8::Task,std::defa [0x13D4C894+52] (C:\Users\qt\work\qt\qtwebengine\src\3rdparty\chromium\base\bind_internal.h:697)
    base::internal::Invoker<base::internal::BindState<void (__thiscall v8::Task::*)(void),std::unique_ptr<v8::Task,std::default_delete<v8::Task> > >,void __cdecl(void)>::RunOnce [0x13D4CCD6+54] (C:\Users\qt\work\qt\qtwebengine\src\3rdparty\chromium\base\bind_internal.h:665)
    base::OnceCallback<void __cdecl(void)>::Run [0x0FB0D184+52] (C:\Users\qt\work\qt\qtwebengine\src\3rdparty\chromium\base\callback.h:98)
    base::TaskAnnotator::RunTask [0x127579C1+993] (C:\Users\qt\work\qt\qtwebengine\src\3rdparty\chromium\base\task\common\task_annotator.cc:144)
    base::internal::TaskTracker::RunSkipOnShutdown [0x1282DA74+36] (C:\Users\qt\work\qt\qtwebengine\src\3rdparty\chromium\base\task\thread_pool\task_tracker.cc:771)
    base::internal::TaskTracker::RunTaskWithShutdownBehavior [0x1282E0FC+60] (C:\Users\qt\work\qt\qtwebengine\src\3rdparty\chromium\base\task\thread_pool\task_tracker.cc:788)
    base::internal::TaskTracker::RunTask [0x1282DFF6+1382] (C:\Users\qt\work\qt\qtwebengine\src\3rdparty\chromium\base\task\thread_pool\task_tracker.cc:635)
    base::internal::TaskTracker::RunAndPopNextTask [0x1282D934+452] (C:\Users\qt\work\qt\qtwebengine\src\3rdparty\chromium\base\task\thread_pool\task_tracker.cc:506)
    base::internal::WorkerThread::RunWorker [0x12841F0C+1452] (C:\Users\qt\work\qt\qtwebengine\src\3rdparty\chromium\base\task\thread_pool\worker_thread.cc:339)
    base::internal::WorkerThread::RunPooledWorker [0x128418E8+24] (C:\Users\qt\work\qt\qtwebengine\src\3rdparty\chromium\base\task\thread_pool\worker_thread.cc:225)
    base::internal::WorkerThread::ThreadMain [0x1284239B+171] (C:\Users\qt\work\qt\qtwebengine\src\3rdparty\chromium\base\task\thread_pool\worker_thread.cc:204)
    base::`anonymous namespace'::ThreadFunc [0x1274B6FC+188] (C:\Users\qt\work\qt\qtwebengine\src\3rdparty\chromium\base\threading\platform_thread_win.cc:112)
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x75F9FA29+25]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x778E7A9E+286]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x778E7A6E+238]
    `anonymous namespace'::InvalidParameter [0x152CF3F3+3] (C:\Users\qt\work\qt\qtwebengine\src\3rdparty\chromium\base\win\process_startup_helper.cc:26)
    invalid_parameter
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: why unity tag??

Comment: Sorry, I am new in the forum. Since my webgl file is created with unity I added it. Now I edit the post and I delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Solved,
for me was necessary to build the project in release mode and then click run. I was building the project in debug mode.